# Resetting System.Threading.Timer using .Change

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Could someone please clarify the correct usage for System.Threading.Timer please.

I have a Server Client acknowledgement response model. What I am aiming to do is resend logged messages from the server, if no acknowledgment is received in after a set period of time.

So when the first message is sent I store a Timer;

```
AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
TestsTimeout timeout = new TestsTimeout(firstTest, _socket);

TimerCallback resendCallback = timeout.ResendMessage;
Timer timeoutTimer = new Timer(resendCallback, autoEvent, timeoutPeriod, timeoutPeriod);
```

Then when a acknowledgement to a message is received I simply want to reset the time back and send the next message out.

```
timeout.Change(0, timeoutPeriod);
```

Now, I followed the MSDN example for this, however, 0 seems to invoke the callback straight away? is this correct? what is the corect way of doing this please?

Comment: Code like this only adds problems, it doesn't solve any.  You already get a perfectly good timeout from the autoEvent's Wait call.  One less threading race bug you'll have to fix.

Comment: Sorry hand could you expand on what you mean by this? Basically I send a message down a web socket from the server which the client will acknowledge back with a message. If the server doesn't receive this I want to resend the last message as a fail safe. How can autoEvent help with this please?

Comment: The point of using an AutoResetEvent is that you, somewhere else in your code, wait for it to be signaled.  Typically with a WaitOne() call, you can specify a timeout in that call.  The secondary concern is exactly what problem you are trying to solve.  If the client doesn't respond then it either hung and resending the message isn't going to solve that.  Or it is heavily loaded and just not getting around to doing the job, in which case you are making the problem worse by giving it more work to do.  If you need a more reliable way than TCP then you should use MessageQueue.

Comment: Thanks for that hans. I'm trying to cover the possibility of lost messages in a web socket connection. My ideas being that I set a timeout where if the acknowledgment isn't sent within the set period I try to send the previous message. I have to use we sockets so tcp isn't really an option here infortunately. I would hope the likelihood of the timeout triggering should be rare

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148(v=vs.110).aspx

> Specify zero (0) to restart the timer immediately.

There you go.

Comment: Yes I find this a little ambiguous? It implies to me that setting to zero would restart it. It seems to trigger it? Does it need to be timeout.infinite in my case?

Comment: Yes, use Timeout.Infinite. Zero is not a special case. When you pass x it means call the callback after x milliseconds. Here, 0 milliseconds.